A Java method which invokes itself?
I have come across this snippet in a Java book (Walter Savitch):
/**
Class whose privacy can be breached.
*/
public class PetPair
{
  private Pet first, second;
  public PetPair(Pet firstPet, Pet secondPet)
  {
    first = firstPet;
    second = secondPet;
  }
  public Pet getFirst()
  {
    return first;
  }
  public Pet getSecond()
  {
    return second;
  }
  public void writeOutput()
  {
    System.out.println("First pet in the pair:");
    first.writeOutput();
    System.out.println("\nSecond pet in the pair:");
    second.writeOutput();
  }
}

What I don't understand is why the method "writeOutput" has, within its body, a call to writeOutput itself. How can a method have the same method within it, i.e., how can a method call itself?? I can understand a method calling ANOTHER method, but this does not make sense to me!
I did not try anything. I did not try running the programme on Eclipse. Why? Because I don't understand the idea behind a method calling itself. If someone could explain this to me, I'd happily run the programme and see the output. I'm sure the programme runs, cause I got it from a book, but running it won't do me any good cause I don't understand the basis.

The writeOutput() method in PetPair is not calling itself, it calls the writeOutput() methods from the Pet instances. Pet != PetPair.

They're different classes, so different methods. One is PetPair#writeOutput the other is Pet#writeOutput. A method that calls itself is called a "recursive method" they exist.

This is an excellent time to try the debugger that comes with Eclipse! It allows you to step through the program line by line to see how the program gets evaluated. Once you reach the first.writeOutput() line, you can click "step into" and see where execution gets taken to. As others have noticed, this is not PetPair, but Pet's writeOutput method.

Aside from the fact that these are different methods... Why do you think a method can't call itself?  What would prevent this from happeming, and what happens when you test that assumption?

OK, "recursive" is the word I was trying desperately to remember, but couldn't. I will have to go back to basics. I now know my understanding is sketchy, at best. Thank you Progman, matt, Botje, and David

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)


What I don't understand is why the method "writeOutput" has, within its body, a call to writeOutput itself.

the method "writeOutput" doesn't call it self, it calls the method writeOutput in the Pet object "first" then it calls the method writeOutput on the Pet object "second".
its calling a method called writeOutput that is in the Pet class not the writeOutput method it self.
if it actually wants to call it self it would call it self as "this.writeOutput()"

@JackTravis Make sure to check out What should I do when someone answers my question? if this was helpful for you!

@JackTravis If this Answer solved your Question, accept and up-vote.
